# Merge 2 record in to record when the column datas are the same in django

Tags: python, django, backend

[image]

How can i get the sum of the 'HARMAN' values into 1 record if the 'KARIŞIM KODU' is the same

```
class ProjeVerileri(models.Model):
    harman = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
    karisim = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.harman +' / ' + self.karisim)
```

and this is my model, in the end i want my data to look like this

[image: in the end i want my data to look like this]

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    karisim=request.POST.get('karisim')
    harman=request.POST.get('harman')
    ProjeVerileri.objects.create(
            karisim=karisim,
            harman = harman,
        )
```

this is my views

Comment: So what exactly do you want? A `QuerySet` or something?

Comment: But you here show a table, exactly what is "feeding" the table? What sort of view, etc. do you use?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem added my views

Comment: So you just want to add up the `harman` in case there exists already a value for that `karisim`, right?

Comment: yes @willeM_VanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view where you create a `ProjectVerileri` can be changed to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    karisim = request.POST.get('karisim')
    harman = request.POST.get('harman')
    item, created = ProjeVerileri.objects.get_or_create(
        karisim=karisim,
        defaults={'harman': harman},
    )
    if not created:
        item.harman += harman
        item.save(update_fields=('harman',))
```

so in case the item already exists, we update it.

If you cleaned the database, i.e. made sure there are no duplicates for `karisim` anymore, you can also enforce this on the model by marking it unique:

```
class ProjeVerileri(models.Model):
    harman = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    karisim = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.harman} / {self.karisim}'
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Comment: ProjeVerileri() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'defaults' getting this error

Comment: @EMREDAL: you likely forgot to rewrite `.create` to `.get_or_create`.